# pygame: resize a surface on which a subclass is based

Tags: python, pygame, surface

I have a game class based on a pygame surface, and I initialise it like this:

```
game_obj(pygame.Surface)
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
      super(game_obj, self).__init__((width, height)
```

Later in the game I want the object to change size, so I called super() again, but it doesn't appear to be the correct size, or when I fill it isn't filling properly.  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: using only `super()` again doesn't change it. Using `super().__init__()` could change it but I would rather create new instance of `game_obj` with new size and copy elements from old instance to new one, and delete old instance. Or I would create object with two surfaces - smaller and bigger and keep both.

Comment: Thanks, doing Surface.init(self, w, h) worked!! Can't see an up arrow so I can mark it as best answer, will do that when the arrow appears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only `super()` again doesn't change it. Using `super().__init__()` could change it but I would rather create new instance of `game_obj` with new size and copy elements from old instance to new one, and delete old instance.

Or I would create object with two surfaces - smaller and bigger - and keep both.

Comment: Unless there is some documented guarantee that calling `__init__()` again doesn't mess things up, I would not recommend this. For instance it could be just calling `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` without freeing the surface from the first `__init__()`.